# Limit for REST API Calls towards Dropbox?

Tags: rest, api, dropbox, limits

Is there a fix number for REST Calls towards Dropbox like 1000 requests per Day etc.

I cant find any Information on the Dropbox site.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API does have a rate limiting system, but there aren't any specific numbers documented. The limits operate on a per-user basis.

Also note that not all 429s and 503s indicate rate limiting, but in any case that you get a 429 or 503 the best practice is to retry the request, respecting the Retry-After header if given in the response, or using an exponential back-off, if not.